# How to show Airplay button in MPMoviePlayerController iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpvolumeview

I have an app in which I am playing a video using `MPMoviePlayerController` with custom controls. I'm adding a feature so that users can mirror the play back in Apple TV for this i have implemented the following code.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeButton = [[MPVolumeView alloc]   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0)];
volumeButton.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
volumeButton.showsRouteButton = YES;
[self.view addSubview:volumeButton];
```

But Airplay button is not visible in iOS 8. Is there any way to show Airplay button in `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Please provide your suggestions and valuable inputs.

Comment: Airplay button will automatically displayed when the device is available in the same WIFI which can able to work with airplay. For example : Apple TV.

Comment: @iAshish not true in iOS 8, there is no way to access the AirPlay button in iOS 8's `MPMoviePlayerController`, you can test it in Mobile Safari